# how can I run php file using php's built in server

Tags: php

How can I run php file using php’s built in web server 
But the php file is a form that will call another php file.

this is the php file that I am running using built in server

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
   <p>this is to compute the Levenshtein distance</p>
   <form action="phpForm.php" target="_blank" method="POST">
    please enter the first string :<br>
    <input type="text" name="string1">
    <br>
    please enter the secondstring:<br>
    <input type="text" name="string2" >
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

when I submit, supposed to open phpForm.php
thos is what I wrote in the command line

```
PHP -S localhost:8000 -t Sites/openSouq form.php
```

Answer (score 2):

On the terminal or command line navigate to the directory that contains your PHP code and run:

```
php -S localhost:8080 -t ./
```

or

```
php -S localhost:8080 -t PATH_TO_PHP_FILES
```

Your mistake is you've ran `php` with the `-t` option that points to a specific file, when it should point to a directory. More information in [the docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php#example-412)

Comment: but in this case it will search for index.php file name that's why I have specified the name of the file

Comment: If you remove the `form.php` from the command can you access `form.php` in the address bar? You shouldn't need to specify the file name on the command line, just the root directory your PHP files reside in and then you can access the files by filename in the address bar.

Comment: If a URI request does not specify a file, then either index.php or index.html in the given directory are returned

Comment: That's correct. But why are you adding `form.php` to the end of the `php` command? That isn't required. If you remove that do you notice any changes?

Comment: I want to run the form.php that's why I am adding the name of the file to the command, I want to run form.php instead of index.php

Comment: Ok. So ... remove `form.php` from the command, and nagivate to http://localhost:8080/form.php. Have you tried this? You are using the command incorrectly, that's why it isn't working.